# Why doesn't anyone care about the whereabouts of Miss Kringle and Tom Dougherty?

Tags: plot-explanation, gotham

In Gotham Season 1,

> Ed killed Tom Dougherty who was dating Miss Kringle.

and in Season 2,

> Ed killed Miss Kringle.

But no-one cares to know where they went?

If you don't come into work without informing your superior, even just for two/three days, they will definitely call you. Even if we ignore that part, there are still friends and family members, but no-one from their friends or families tried to find either of them or find out what had happened to them.

The first real suspicion anyone had was Lee about Miss Kringle - but that was only after a long time had passed, and he wasn't exactly a close friend to her.

Why doesn't anyone seem to care about Miss Kringle and Officer Dougherty's wherebouts, especially considering they were both working for the G.C.P.D.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Tom Dougherty:**

He was a douchebag and doesn't seems to have many friends in the department. Miss Kringle found the note about him leaving Gotham which Nygma forged. Gotham is a city where crime is at its peak, and a police officer running away like that doesn't seem surprising.

**Kristen Kringle:**

Nygma was trustworthy until then and was dating Kringle, so when he told Leslie Thompkins that Kringle had reconciled her relationship with Dougherty and left Gotham, she trusted him.

People just trusted what Nygma told them, because they thought he was trustworthy. And we don't know about their families; they might have had no-one of their own, it's possible in a city where people die so frequently. Plus, they work in a police station which is always too busy to care about them.